# Excel Interpolate with logarithmic prediction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a function within Excel to Interpolate while taking into account a logarithmic prediction?

At the moment I am using linear interpolation but would like to find a better way to fill in the blanks if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's no logarithmic regression or interpolation in Excel, even in the Anlaysis ToolPak. You'll need much more advanced software for that, such as MatLab.

If you're stuck working in Excel... here's a possible mathematical solution:

Rather than working with the raw data x and y, instead try plotting `x` and `a^y`, where `a` is the base. (Or plotting `log(x,a)` against `y`.) If you have the correct base `a` (and there's no vertical offset), you will then have a linear relationship from which you can perform a linear interpolation as normal, then convert the interpolated values back to actual values by taking the log of them.

If you don't know what `a` is, then you can instead calculate a line of best fit for an arbitrary a, calculate the standard residuals, and then use Problem Solver to modify `a` until you get the lowest possible standard residuals, at which point you have the best estimate of `a`.

Similarly if there is a vertical offset `b`, you'll need to test some variables there that also result in a linear relationship. Plot `x` against `a^(y-b)`